# How to flatten chicken wire?

Tags: pest-control, raised-beds

We're trying to flatten chicken wire (for our raised bed fence) that came in a roll originally. Any tips?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll never get it completely flat before you use it, though it will tend to flatten over time.

To get most of the curl out, unroll it "upside down" so that the wire on the end bites into the ground. Put a couple of cement blocks or something heavy on that end. Roll out the rest of the fence, putting weights on it wherever it wants to curl back up. Leave it for a couple of days.

Or, don't bother trying to flatten it before you use it. The curl only has enough strength to be annoying, not enough to undo itself from where you attach it. Drive in stakes where you want the perimeter of the fence. Unroll the first bit of fence and attach it to the first stake. Stretch the fence as you unroll it and tie it to the next stake. Continue, stretching the fence so it stays tight and flat, and making sure to attach it to the stakes as you go.

Comment: Agree with bstpierre. If you are stretching the chicken wire tight as you attach it to the fence posts, the fence will appear flat.

Comment: When I put up my garden fence, I used chicken wire with 2"x2" cedar stakes. I would recommend a staple gun with stainless or galvanized staples for attaching the chicken wire. That way you can stretch the wire tight between the stakes and then staple it to keep it stretched. The curl won't be apparent at all if you get it tight enough.